# What's the OCaml naming convention for "constructors"?

Tags: ocaml, naming-conventions, conventions

An OCaml module usually contains at least one abstract type whose idiomatic name is `t`. Also, there's usually a function that constructs a value of that type.

What is the usual / idiomatic name for this?

The StdLib is not consistent here. For example:

- There's `Array.make` and a deprecated function `Array.create`. So that function should be named `make`?
- On the other hand, there's `Buffer.create` but not `Buffer.make`. So that function should be named `create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question when I picked up the language a long time ago. I never use `make` and I think few people do.

Nowadays I use `create` for heavy, often imperative or stateful values, e.g. a [Unicode text segmenter](http://erratique.ch/software/uuseg/doc/Uuseg.html#VALcreate). And I use `v` for, functional, lighter values in DSL/combinator based settings, e.g. the various constructors in Gg, for example for [2D vectors](http://erratique.ch/software/gg/doc/Gg.V2.html#VALv), or [colors](http://erratique.ch/software/gg/doc/Gg.Color.html#VALv).

As camlspotter mentions in his answer the standard library distinguishes  `make` and `create` for values that need an initial value to fill in. I think it's better to be regular here and always use `create` regardless. If your values support an optional initial fill value, add an optional argument to `create` rather than multiply the API entry points.

Answer (score 5):

Some people find this way of module design makes OCaml programming easier, but this is not a mandatory OCaml programming style, and I do not think there is no official name for it. I personally call it "1-data-type-per-1-module" style. (I wrote [a blog post about this](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/camlspotter/20121216/1355686499) but it is in Japanese. I hope some autotranslator gives some useful information to you ...)

Defining a module dedicated to one data type and fix the name of the type `t` has some values:

#### Nice namespacing

Module names explain about what its type and values are, therefore you do not need to repeat type names inside: `Buffer.add_string` instead of `add_string_to_buffer`, and `Buffer.create` instead of `create_buffer`. You can also avoid typing the same module names with local module open:

```
let f () =
  let open Buffer in
  let b = create 10 in   (* instead of Buffer.create *)
  add_string b "hello";  (* instead of Buffer.add_string *)
  contents b             (* instead of Buffer.contents *)
```

#### Easy ML functor application

If an ML functor takes an argument module with a data type, we have a convention that the type should be called `t`.  Modules with data type `t` are easily applied to these functors without renaming of the type.

---

For `Array.create` and `Array.make`, I think this is to follow the distinction of `String.create` and `String.make`.

- `String.create` is to create a string with uninitialized contents. The created string contains random bytes.
- `String.make` is to create a string filled with the given `char`.

We had `Array.create` for long, to create an array whose contents are filled with the given value.  This behavior corresponds with `String.make` rather than `String.create`.  That's why it is now renamed to `Array.make`, and `Array.create` is obsolete.

We cannot have `Array.create` in OCaml with the same behaviour of `String.create`. Unlike strings, arrays cannot be created without initialization, since random bytes may not represent a valid OCaml value for the content in general, which leads to a program crash.

Following this, personally I use `X.create` for a function to create an `X.t` which does not require an initial value to fill it. I use `X.make` if it needs something to fill.

Comment: I would rather use an optional argument to `create` as the fill value to avoid needlessly multiplying the API entry points.

Comment: I believe the second part should come first, as that actually answers the question. The first part is not related to the question at all (and should discuss/compare different style to be complete).

Comment: @DanielBünzli Nice point but the question is more about existing practice, especially as it exists in the standard library. I think that camlspotter caught it pretty well.

Comment: For me the question is what is "the usual / idiomatic name for this ?" in the sense which strategy should I adopt when I create a library and while camlspotter's analysis is right w.r.t. to the standard library, I wouldn't follow/perpetuate this design strategy.

Comment: And this especially since the subtle difference between `make` and `create` as described above doesn't really show up in the meaning of the words themselves, or at least not to the non-native english speaker that I am.

Comment: As a native speaker, `create` implies perhaps a little more effort or production from scratch, but it's a really minor connotative difference and it certainly doesn't direct me to remember one as including initialization.

Comment: So the convention is then even the converse of what a native english speaker may think...